# Seam redirection with condition based on EL

Tags: jboss, seam

I have a seam web application.
During the user navigation I want to above the user to access again to login page, after successfull login.
When user is log-in successfully it is redirected to home.xhtml page. 
If (after login) the user type again the url of login page I want to redirect it automatically to home.

I tried with Seam pages.xml:

```
<page view-id="/common/jsp/login.xhtml">
    <navigation>
        <rule if="#{myUserBean.isUserAlreadyAuthenticated()} ">
            <redirect view-id="/home.xhtml"/>
        </rule>
    </navigation>
```

but it doesnt' work. Probably because Seam manual specify:

> Rules work by evaluating the return value of the action method; it is
>   not possible to evaluate an arbitrary EL expression.

But in my case it doesnt'come from any specific action, the user is asking for login page from an already logged session, where he can have alredy did a lot of actions, or also no one.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I should have solved in this way:

```
<page view-id="/common/jsp/login.xhtml" action ="#{myUserBean.isUserAlreadyAuthenticated()}">
<navigation>
    <rule if-outcome="true">
        <redirect view-id="/home.xhtml"/>
    </rule>
</navigation>
```